# create react app how to change phone app logo background color

Tags: icons, create-react-app, manifest.json

I have an app that I've added as a shortcut onto my phone. I was able to change the logo to the image I wanted, but I can't figure out how to change the background color of the app square from it's default black to a different color.

Here is the image that currently displays on my phone:
[image]

basically I want the black background to be a blue one. The image I am using is a vector so no, the background is not black on the image itself, it's just the white barbell.

I have tried changing both the theme_color and background_color in the manifest.json file but it didn't help.

Can someone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out, I used maskable.app editor and made the logo shape and color that I wanted, then uploaded that as the .png file